# IIS7 URL Rewrite rule for service versioning scenario

Tags: rest, iis-7, url-rewriting, versioning, url-rewrite-module

To version a RESTful service, I would like to do the following with the URL Rewrite Module;

Map https://server/service/ to server/service/v1/ if the Accept header (HTTP_ACCEPT?) is application/vnd.mycompany.service+xml

For the next version of the service, I'd like to bump the version number of the media type, and deploy a v2, so that I can do the following mapping:

Map https://server/service/ to server/service/v2/ if the Accept header (HTTP_ACCEPT?) is application/vnd.mycompany.service-2+xml

I've tried the following rule, but I can't get it to work:

```
<rules>
   <rule name="Route request to correct service version" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
      <match url="*service*" />
         <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT}" pattern="application/vnd.mycompany.*" />
         </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="Service/v1/{R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
   </rule>
</rules>
```

Any help appreciated!

--larsw

Answer (score 2):

Being unfamiliar with the URL rewriting mechanism, I can't help you directly, however, if you were to host your service with [Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/), then a HttpMessageHandler would be able to do this kind of URL conversion based on the accept header.

Comment: We need to launch the v1 of the service in March, so the Web API is a no-go. We'll probably rewrite from a WCF 4.0 webHttpBinding-based service to Web API later.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

a) Somehow the RedirectModule wasn't wired up in applicationHost.config.
b) The following configuration worked:

```
<rule name="Route request to correct service version" patternSyntax="Wildcard">                           
  <match url="*service*" />                                                                  
       <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="true">                                    
          <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT}" pattern="*application/vnd.mycompany.*" />                             
       </conditions>                                                                                      
       <action type="Rewrite" url="service/v1{R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />                  
</rule>
```

c) I had an extra slash before the {R:2} variable that caused the rewritten url to have a double slash.

--larsw